# How to define the 'case insensitive' modifier i in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following JavaScript code:

```
var res = 'text';
    var regex = new RegExp(res);

    var str = 'My text';
    if (str.match(regex)) {
      alert('found word');
    }
```

I need to inform `RegExp` that the`res` variable can be uppercase or lowercase. Something like this: `str.match (regex / i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

`new RegExp(res, 'i')`

Is what you need.